# How can i change the SCSS variable's values in SCSS?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, media-queries

```
$backgroundColor:red;

#deneme{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: $backgroundColor;
}

@media (max-width:1000px){
    $backgroundColor:green;
    #deneme{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: $backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

`Hi, I have a code that changes SCSS variable's value and change the color of a div. It works correctly, but when I write it this way,`

```
$backgroundColor:red;

@media (max-width:1000px){
    $backgroundColor:green;
}

#deneme{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: $backgroundColor;
}
```

it doesn't work and the color will be red for all the pixel values. I want to know why, because I want to use this method and  change the variable's value, then import this value in other SCSS files. Could you please help me about how to make this happen? Thanks in advance.

I want to create a SCSS file in my Nextjs project and change the some variable's value according to px value of the screen and then I want to use this variables in different SCSS files. I need some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that code fences [use three backticks](/markdown). Not four. Look at your post and then [edit] it to use proper markdown. Having said that: it might make sense to use normal CSS variables instead of SCSS variables here, since you're not doing anything that _needs_ SCSS variable logic.

Comment: You are using the same variable for the same media query. Why?

Comment: It is just an example to define my problem. I am not gonna use this code in my project. I want to change the variable's values  using media query then I am gonna use this variable in other SCSS files. I do not want to go each file and change the variable's value using media query. So I will change it in a file and export this variables.